# Remote debugging Flink local cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to deploy my jobs on a local Flink cluster during development (i.e. JobManager and TaskManager running on my development laptop), and use remote debugging. I tried adding 
"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" to the flink-conf.yaml file. Since job and task manager are running on the same machine, the task manager throws exception stating that the socket is already in use and terminates. Is there any way I can get this running.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably setting `env.java.opts`, which affects all JVMs started by Flink. Since the jobmanager gets started first, it grabs the port before the taskmanager is started.

You can use `env.java.opts.taskmanager` to pass parameters only for taskmanager JVMs.